# C++ Filling, ios::app is working, but not ios::in

Tags: c++, string, file

Here is my code where I try to Append to a file and also read it.
Appending is working great however reading is not working.
Is it the problem of getline?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   fstream ob1;
   ob1.open("testext", ios::app | ios::in);

   ob1 << "1\n";
   ob1.write("Write\n", 5);

   while (ob1)
   {
       cout << "1" << endl; // Check if compiler goes in while loop
       string a;
       getline(ob1, a);
       cout << a << endl;
   }
   ob1.close();
}
```

Output

```
1
```

Comment: maybe you need to reopen it/seek 0 ?

Comment: FYI: A similar question I answered just recently: [fstream::write and fstream::read changing both reading and writing pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72292827/7478597)

Comment: An `fstream` only has a single file position, used for *either* reading or writing. When changing mode, you have to first do a seek to reposition it.

Answer (score 1):

you could close the file and reopen it but it would be silly
you could use

```
    //writing code here

    //to push all text to the file and not making errors
    ob1.flush(); 
    // to return reading pointer to the beginning of the file
    ob1.seekg(0,ios_base::beg); 
    
    //reading code here
```

and side note : use

```
    string a; 
   while (getline(ob1, a))
   {
       cout << "1" << endl; // Check if compiler goes in while loop
       cout << a << endl;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing into the file you are trying to reading its contents. So after performing any one of the operation you need to close the stream and open it again in order to perform different set of operation.

So before while loop add these below 2 lines,

```
ob1.close( );
ob1.open("testext", ios::app | ios::in);
```